# What is the name of this D-shaped electrical component symbol?

Tags: transistors, symbol

I believe that there is a missing component in the highlighted area.

What is that component?

I have done some research and found that symbol corresponds to a transistor but I'm not sure what type of transistor is it.

[image]

Comment: It's not possible to tell just from the silk screen outline

Comment: Presumably, a bipolar junction transistor (BJT). Type and polarity undefined.

Comment: The symbol indicates a bipolar transistor in the TO-92 package with the unusual pinout EBC (TO-92 BJTs are usually CBE or BCE, in my experience). Beyond that we can't tell. Knowing what it's used for might help understand what parts would work there.

Comment: You are correct in identifying the usual PCB markings for a transistor. You can read ebc (emitter, base, collector) and Q3 where Q is a common, conventional designation for a transistor. However it is impossible to say what type of transistor is missing just from your image of the PCB. We would need a circuit diagram in order to work it out. Can you reverse engineer the board and update your question? Since there appear to be spaces for other missing components, maybe the board is used in more than one application and your equipment does not need the omitted components.

Comment: It's a US-standard-pinout transistor (BJT) in TO-92 pinout. Eg. 2N4401 or 2N4403 (NPN vs. PNP). Maybe something to do with the missing SPK1 (speaker?) connector, assuming the part was never installed. There could well be other related parts missing.

Comment: It's not "missing", it's "not populated". That's a deliberate choice made by the manufacturer of that device, since presumably that transistor is not use din the version of the device you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That symbol is called an "outline",in this case  it approximates the D shaped cross-section shape of a TO-92 package.

[image]
image credit RS-online

The writing `Q3` and `e` `b` `c` strongly suggests a bipolar transistor, but there are thousands of different types.

If you can locate a service manual for your appliance it may indicate what feature is provided by that transistor and what part to use and any other changes needed to enable that feature.  it may well be associated with the missing connector `CH1` `spk` (perhaps an optional loudspeaker)

If this is a LM8560 clock radio these parts that could be for the the speaker for the non-radio option.  but I'm guessing coffee maker instead, and possibly a newer chip than LM8560. perhaps they they want to be able to use that board as an alarm clock, the speaker connects to SPK and the battery backup to BT1.

If my guesses are close and you want to experiment with this try PN2222  for the transistor and a 16 ohm speaker. there may be a resistor needed also - try 1K.

Answer (score 1):

If the SPK CH1 header or wires were included the the BJT would have likely been included.

Since you did not mention any problems this omission was intentional for some other purpose. (Option)

The EBC silkscreen is a common [orientation](https://www.google.com/search?q=pn2222a) for general purpose low power TO-92 package bipolar transistors.

If you aren't missing a speaker, you won't miss Q1.